# Formats for writing a thesis in Mathematics

Tags: formatting, document-classes, classicthesis, thesis

What are the usual formats for writing a thesis in Mathematics in Latex ?

Comment: `amsbook`? That's what they used at my grad school, at least. Or, rather, they used a customised class based on `amsbook`.

Comment: You should inquire about these requirements from your institution, since each have their own. If they don't, then there are plenty to choose from.

Comment: see also the tugboat article by peter flynn: [A university thesis class: automation and its pitfalls](http://www.tug.org/tug2012/booklet/flynn/flynn00.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of different classes for writing a thesis.

In Linux I used the following command line and found this

```
$ locate thesis | grep cls
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/seuthesis/zharticle/zharticle.cls.gz
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adfathesis/adfathesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/afthesis/afthesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ebsthesis/ebsthesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elteikthesis/elteikthesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fbithesis/fbithesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gatech-thesis/gatech-thesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hepthesis/hepthesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kdgdocs/kdgmasterthesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/msu-thesis/msu-thesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/muthesis/muthesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/muthesis/third-rep.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ryethesis/ryethesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sapthesis/sapthesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/seuthesis/seuthesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stellenbosch/usthesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tabriz-thesis/tabriz-thesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thuthesis/thuthesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/uaclasses/my-thesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/uaclasses/ua-thesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/uadocs/uamasterthesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/uafthesis/uafthesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucdavisthesis/ucdavisthesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucthesis/ucthesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/uestcthesis/uestcthesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/uiucthesis/uiucthesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/umich-thesis/umich-thesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/umthesis/umthesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/uothesis/uothesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/uowthesis/UoWthesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ut-thesis/ut-thesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/uwthesis/uwthesis.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/york-thesis/york-thesis.cls
```

Most of the classes belongs to particular Universities or Institutes.

If your institution has not a custom LaTeX class... you could start with a report class (or from one of the above) and customize it to satisfy the parameters of your University.

Cheers!

Of course, keep asking, if you need help with the customization! ;-)